# How to pass a variable into another function to be called - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am trying to get this to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form><input type='button' id='confirm' value="Confirm"/></form>
<p id="getvariable"></p>

<script> 
function a(){var t= 5;}
function b(){return t;}

document.getElementById('confirm').onclick = function(){
document.getElementById("getvariable").innerHTML = b();}

</script>
</body>
```

but I can't pass a variable to the other function. Any help would be great!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Error message? Unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the variable t is in the scope of the function a when you set it. It needs to be global. Like this:

```
var t = 0;
function a(){ t = 5;}
function b(){return t;}

document.getElementById('confirm').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("getvariable").innerHTML = b();
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/noprenth/)

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply! What if I want the getvariable to show 5. How do I make variable t=5?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a value in another function that has been defined locally in a particular function.

So this is wrong:

```
function a(){var t= 5;}
function b(){return t;}
```

What I would do is :

```
var t=0;
function a(){t= 5;}
function b(){return t;}

document.getElementById('confirm').onclick = function(){
document.getElementById("getvariable").innerHTML = b();}
```

Here's a link that can help you : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

**t** valriable should be decalred outside the function scope

```
    var t = 0;
    function a(){
      t = 5;
    }
    function b(){
      return t;
    }

    document.getElementById('confirm').onclick = function(){
      document.getElementById("getvariable").innerHTML = b();
   }
```